# Meteor.js How to subscribe on DB changes on server side

Tags: python, meteor, server-side, publish-subscribe, subscribe

I am a new in meteor.js and I am in a bit of a jam.

The main idea of the app is to let the user send a file to the server using the client and the server runs python code on the file and returns the result (via MongoDB)

I am trying to write a small app the has a simple form on the client side. This form gets a link to the google drive spreadsheet and saves it in a MongoDB.
I am looking for a way to subscribe (observeChanges) to changes in the DB on the server.

It's should be something like this:

```
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection('tasks');


if (Meteor.isServer){
  Meteor.publish('tasks', function() {
    return Tasks.find();
  });

  Meteor.publish("tasks", function(){
    var subHandle = Tasks.find().observeChanges({
    added: function (contacts,template,createdAt) {
        publication.added(contacts,template,createdAt);
        consule.log("added");
    },
    changed: function(id, fields) {
      consule.log("changed");
    },
    removed: function (id) {
      consule.log("moved");
    }
  });
  });

}

if (Meteor.isClient){
    Meteor.subscribe('tasks');
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do with the results of your observers. (a) You shouldn't publish twice with the same name ("tasks"), (b) your second publication doesn't `return` anything. (c) if you're trying to observe the changes on the client side then just put your observers there!

Comment: Consider using [meteor-collection-hooks](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks) package.